# More Intelligent IntelliSense - Focus on local variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Using Visual Studio 2010, I keep running into a very annoying habit in its IntelliSense feature.  Instead of prioritizing local variables and properties, it seems to default to picking whatever random class out of the standard libraries happens to have the same sequence of characters in the name.  It's almost invariably some class I've never heard of or had any use for, and always completely inappropriate in the context.  I'm finding myself having to type everything out fully instead, which begs the question of why I have IntelliSense in the first place?

Is there a way to make it choose local variables or properties first, since those are the things I'm most likely to use?  Or failing that, it should choose classes within my current project over obscure random classes from the depths of the standard libraries.  I know other IDEs work like this, such as Eclipse.  I've looked at the options in VS, and pretty much the only thing I can do that helps is to check the "Pre-select most recently used member".  That's great, but it seems like it should be possible to do better than that, perhaps keeping a stack of recently used members so you can get the next-most-recently used, etc.

Comment: @HighCore.  Is there a freeware product that would work?

Comment: @HighCore I'm afraid I'm on a shoe-string budget here.  I was hoping there'd be a free solution out there somewhere.  But I'll put it on my wishlist for when there's some money to spare...

Comment: You could try some of the intellisense extensions for VS2010: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B0%5D.Value=intellisense&f%5B1%5D.Type=VisualStudioVersion&f%5B1%5D.Value=10.0&f%5B1%5D.Text=Visual%20Studio%202010&f%5B2%5D.Type=CostCategory&f%5B2%5D.Value=Free&f%5B2%5D.Text=Free

Comment: @BgRva A good resource, but I don't see anything on that list that improves C# IntelliSense at all, just a bunch of additions for other languages mainly, and one that adds some type filtering, which I might try, but don't think it addresses the main problem.